# Insert the ID of the same Component into Input

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I need to pass the id of the element inside the typescript with [theID] of the :

```
<ng-template #popTitle let-language="language">Error</ng-template>
<ng-template #popContent let-greeting="greeting">{{texto}}!</ng-template>
<a
    type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary ml-5" placement="top"
    [ngbPopover]="popContent" [popoverTitle]="popTitle"
    triggers="manual" [theID]="#p1" #p1="ngbPopover" (click)="toggleWithGreeting(p1, 'Bonjour')">
</a>
```

To be able to access from the parent the parameter that will remain inside

In short, the question is how can I use `[var] = "# id"`

The practical use that I am going to give it is in the toggleWithGreeting function where when invoking it from another place I have to pass the id of the element, for this I plan to put it inside in an input and call it from the father

Comment: Hi!
You want to call child function from parent component?
If so, check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bwtucu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: No, I can do that now, what I need is to measure the ID inside the typeScript

Comment: I need to put it in like a "this", telling him to put the element I'm in

Answer (score 0):

I used an ViewChild()

```
  @ViewChild("id") p1:PopoverComponent;
```

I've given it too many laps and I haven't fallen for the obvious